# Can't access array data from API call when using map() in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm attempting to map over data I received from an API call. Getting shallow endpoints works fine, but anything nested gives me an error.

The goal is to get all of the opening themes and display them in a 'ul'.

The exact error "TypeError: anime.opening_themes is undefined"

[Repo to the project](https://github.com/dvlprdave/AniPlex)

Heres the endpoints.

[image]

Heres my component.

```
const AnimeDetails = (props) => {
  const API = 'https://api.jikan.moe/v3/anime'

  const initialState = {
    anime: []
  }

  const [anime, setAnime] = useState(initialState)

  useEffect(() => {
    const getAnime = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`${API}/${props.match.params.animeId}`)
      const data = await response.json()

      console.log(data);
      setAnime(data) // set initial state to hold data from our API call
    }
    getAnime()
  }, []) // [] prevents useEffect from running in an infinite loop

  return (
    <AnimeDetailsWrapper>
      <Title>{anime.title}</Title>
      <Details>
        {anime.opening_themes
          .map((song, index) => (
            <li key={index}>{song}</li>
          ))}
      </Details>
    </AnimeDetailsWrapper>
  )
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to array-destructure an object...?

Comment: Can you please provide an animeId. I will check from my side.

Comment: I've edited the question and added a link to the repo.

Answer (score 2):

Your initial state is an empty array, not an empty object:

```
const initialState = {
  anime: []
}
```

When your component mounts, there is no data yet, so you're attempting to render `[].opening_themes.map`, and obviously there is no `opening_themes` property on an empty array.

Set your initial state to an empty object instead:

```
const initialState = {}
```

And you will probably want to test that you have data before attempting to render it:

```
return anime.mal_id && (
    <AnimeDetailsWrapper>
      <Title>{anime.title}</Title>
      <Details>
        {anime.opening_themes
          .map((song, index) => (
            <li key={index}>{song}</li>
          ))}
      </Details>
    </AnimeDetailsWrapper>
  )
```

This will prevent your component from rendering anything until your `anime` state contains a `mal_id` property.

Comment: You beat me to it.

Comment: The initial state is not an empty array, but an object that has a property `anime` which is an array

Comment: @Dave.Q notice the `return anime.mal_id && (` which prevents the rendering if the anime is not yet received from the endpoint. If it's still fail, please provide a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: I've added the repo to the question.

Comment: @Dave.Q an external reference to the repo is tolerated, but only if the relevant code is in the question. Also, the repo is not up to date with the code in your question, so it's rather useless...

Answer (score 0):

The first time you render your component, the state `anime` is equal to `{anime: []}`, which has no property called `opening_themes`.

Answer (score 0):

you should try like this

first, remove initialState code and use direct code like following

if the response is in the form of an array

```
const [anime, setAnime] = useState([])
```

if the response is in the form of an object

```
const [anime, setAnime] = useState({})
```

otherwise, null will work with any response

```
const [anime, setAnime] = useState(null)
```

return code like this

```
 return (
  <>  {anime && <AnimeDetailsWrapper>
      <Title>{anime.title}</Title>
      <Details>
        {anime.opening_themes
          .map((song, index) => (
            <li key={index}>{song}</li>
          ))}
      </Details>
    </AnimeDetailsWrapper>}</>
  )
```